# JPA CriteriaBuilder count returns wrong data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to count my rows with conditions birthId which I have from AnimalFilter and deleteDatetime which is always null. It returns me strange values -> similar for every birthId but they are different in my database.
What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
 @Repository
public class AnimalSearchCount {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    Long countBy(AnimalFilter filter) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);

        Root<Animal> animal = cq.from(Animal.class);

        Predicate deleteDatetimePredicate = cb.isNull(animal.get("deleteDateTime"));

        if (filter.getBirthId() != null) {
            cq.select(cb.count(animal.get("birth").get("id")));
            cq.where(deleteDatetimePredicate);
        }

        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (filter.getBirthId() != null) {
     cq.select(cb.count(animal));
     cq.where(
         deleteDatetimePredicate, 
         cb.eq(animal.get("birth").get("id"), filter.getBirthId()));
}
```